# How to get all entries using query state with Dapr?

Tags: .net, dapr

I use state store in Dapr to save and get items to/from Redis using .NET client, it works fine. Now I need to **get all entries with query state**. I try different forms of query:

```cs
var query1 = """
    {
      "filter": {}
    }
    """;
var query2 = """
    "filter": {}
    """;
var query3 = "{}";

var queryResult = await daprClient.QueryStateAsync<Product>("statestore", query, cancellationToken: ct);
```

But I constantly get `failed query in state store statestore: query index not found`:

```
Dapr.DaprException: Query state operation failed: the Dapr endpointed indicated a failure. See InnerException for details.
       ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="failed query in state store statestore: query index not found")
         at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.QueryStateAsync[TValue](String storeName, String jsonQuery, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

What is the correct form for the query? Or do I need to initialize the store? I haven't found anytning about that in the documentation.

Comment: What is the query value supposed to be if you want "all" records?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to run a version of Redis that has 2 modules enabled:

1. RediSearch: a full-featured search engine
2. RedisJSON: a native JSON data type

This can be done by using this `docker` command:

```
 docker run --name redis2 -d -p 6380:6379 redislabs/redismod
```

Next, add query indexes to your Dapr config as described [here](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-state-stores/setup-redis/#querying-json-objects-optional).

Example:

```yaml
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: "localhost:6380"
  - name: queryIndexes
    value: |
      [
        {
          "name": "orgIndx",
          "indexes": [
            {
              "key": "person.org",
              "type": "TEXT"
            },
            {
              "key": "state",
              "type": "TEXT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Finally, in your query, add metadata to indicate which index should be used for that specific query, like this:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> metadata = new() { "contentType", "application/json" }, { "queryIndexName", "orgIndx" } };
var queryResult = await daprClient.QueryStateAsync<Product>("statestore", query, cancellationToken: ct, metadata: metadata);
```

Make sure to pass at least the `contentType` metadata during your write operations too.

Once completed, your query will work.
Keep an eye [on this](https://github.com/dapr/cli/issues/906) GH issue, and upvote, as this is clearly not a great developer experience ootb.